# Why is Nebula NatTable better in handling large data sets?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, nattable

Many people are telling me that Nebula NatTable is better for handling large amount of data. When I ask how it is better no one is giving me correct answer. Could anyone please tell me why NatTable is best for handling large amount of data? How does it differ from other tables in handling large amount of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NatTable is a virtual table by design. This means for rendering it only processes the data that is visible to the user. Especially with regards to a large number of columns this is a big difference to other table implementations. Additionally the usage of GlazedLists brings performance optimizations.

If you have a look at our getting started tutorial you probably find some additional information I forgot.

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html

Comment: Thanks sir. Yes i was looking to get started on Nattable. Thanks for the tutorial link